# Performance improvements to tint menu icons

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-vectordrawable

I want to tint my menu icons, the visible ones with one color and the ones in the overflow menu with a different color.
So I wrote following code:

```
    final MenuBuilder builder = getMenuBuilder(menu);
    if (builder != null) {
        builder.flagActionItems();
        final ArrayList<MenuItemImpl> items = builder.getVisibleItems();
        for (int i = 0, size = items.size(); i < size; ++i) {
            final MenuItemImpl item = items.get(i);
            final Drawable icon = item.getIcon();
            if (icon != null) {
                final Drawable mutate = icon.mutate();
                if (item.isActionButton()) {
                    mutate.setColorFilter(actionItemColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                } else {
                    mutate.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
                item.setIcon(mutate);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works perfectly but I am not pleased with the performance, especially since I started using vector drawables.
Here is a measurement of three vector icons, the thee icons are visible directly. But the call to flagActionItems() takes about 160ms... This seems a bit much.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to improve the performance. The code needs to work on Android 4.2 and newer.

Comment: What is the bottom image and how do you access that view?